# An unexpected error occured

Tags: google-apps-script

So I was playing around with this script...

```
function driveAutoTrash(){ try{
var garbage = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B-UDPaPCh-pjUUt3aHRIekJQOXM")
var garbagefolders = garbage.getFolders();
var garbagefiles = garbage.getFiles();
while(garbagefolders.hasNext()){
  var folder = garbagefolders.next();
  folder.setTrashed(true);
}while(garbagefiles.hasNext()){
  var file = garbagefiles.next();
  file.setTrashed(true)
}}}
```

and when I try to set triggers for it with the "Current project's triggers" thing, it throws "An unexpected error occured" with a button to dismiss it. Any ideas? (yes, it does have a catch with the try)